# Populating a Picker with firestore resulting in failed child context type error

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, native-base, react-native-firebase

I have been trying to populate a picker from a list in a firestore doc. Picker works if the data is created within the app but receive an error if I use data that comes from my database.

```
Warning: Failed child context type: Invalid child context `virtualizedCell.cellKey` of type `number` supplied to `CellRenderer`, expected `string`.    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:681)
in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:726)
in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:820)
in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1009)
in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:640)
in FlatList (at Picker.ios.js:188)
in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:726)
in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:820)
in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:329)
in _class (at Content.js:10)
in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Content) (at Picker.ios.js:187)
in RCTView (at View.js:71)
in View (at Container.js:15)
in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Container) (at Picker.ios.js:185)
in RCTView (at View.js:71)
in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
in RCTView (at View.js:71)
in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
in AppContainer (at Modal.js:238)
in RCTView (at View.js:71)
in View (at Modal.js:257)
in RCTModalHostView (at Modal.js:244)
in Modal (at Picker.ios.js:176)
in RCTView (at View.js:71)
in View (at Picker.ios.js:174)
in PickerNB (at connectStyle.js:384)
...
```

This happens regardless of which way I try to import my data. It result in my Picker item not being shown in Android and shown in IOS but cannot read the data properly.

this is my package.json file.

```
"native-base": "^2.3.9",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.53.0",
"react-native-firebase": "^3.2.4",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0"
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    AppRegistry,
    ListView
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { Container, Content, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title, Text, List, ListItem, Form, Input, Label, Item, Picker } from 'native-base'

const companies = ["Choose a Company"]

export default class EditScreen extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.onChangeSpcompany = this.onChangeSpcompany.bind(this)
        this.companies = [];
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            companiesDataSource: ds,
            companies: null
        }
    }

componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        companies: this.props.navigation.state.params.companies
    })
    firebase.firestore().doc('companyList/list').get().then(doc => {
        let data = doc.data();
        for(let company in data){
            console.log(data[company])
            this.companies.push(`${data[company]}`)
        }
    })
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchCompanies()
    // this.state.companies.map((l, i) => {
    //     console.log(l, i)
    // })
    console.log(this.state.companies)
    if(this.state.companies !== null){
        for(let company in this.state.companies){
            console.log(company)
        }
        // this.state.companies.forEach(element => {
        //     console.log(element)
        // })
    }
}

fetchCompanies(){
    firebase.firestore().doc('companyList/list').get().then(doc => {
        this.setState({
            companiesDataSource: `this.state.companiesDataSource.cloneWithRows(doc.data()),
            companies: doc.data()
        })
    })
}

onChangeSpcompany(value){
        this.setState({
            spcompany: value
        })
}

renderRow(company){
    return(
        <Picker.Item label={company} value={company}/>
    )
}
```

This is the view

```
render() {
    let choiceArray = []
    for(let company in this.state.companies){
        let data = this.state.companies
        let brick = (
            <Picker.Item key={`${data[company]}`} label={data[company]} value={company}/>
        )
        choiceArray.push(brick)
    }
    return(
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <Form>
                    <List>
                        <Item>
                            <Label>{I18n.t('spcompany')}</Label>
                            <Picker
                                iosHeader="Select one"
                                mode="dropdown"
                                style={{ width:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? undefined : 140 }}
                                selectedValue={this.state.spcompany}
                                onValueChange={(value, index) => this.onChangeSpcompany(value)}
                                placeholder={this.state.spcompany}
                            >
                                {choiceArray}
                                {/* { this.companies.map((company, index) => {
                                    console.log(company)
                                    return <Picker.Item key={`company${index}`} label={company} value={company}/>
                                })} */}
                                {/* <ListView 
                                    dataSource={this.state.companiesDataSource}
                                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                                /> */}
                            </Picker>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <Label>{I18n.t('lang')}</Label>
                            <Picker
                                iosHeader="Select one"
                                mode="dialog"
                                prompt='Select one'
                                style={{ width:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? undefined : 140 }}
                                selectedValue={this.state.language}
                                onValueChange={value => this.onChangeLanguage(value)}
                            >   
                                <Picker.Item label="English" value="en" />
                                <Picker.Item label="Français" value="fr" />
                            </Picker>
                        </Item>
                    </List>
                </Form>
                <Button block onPress={this.handleEdit} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>{I18n.t('editProfile')}</Text>
                </Button>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I know there is redundancy in my code, I was trying several things but they all end up with the same result. The weird part is that even if I make sure that my key is a string a receive a mistake. How can I fix this mistake?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? When you select a value does it update or it stays the same?

Comment: You might wanna upgrade the library to the latest version, it seems to be fixed with version 2.3.10 https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1571